# Turning points in a squared first order ODE using Scipy.integrate

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, physics, ode

I am trying to code a radius function based on the Schwarzchild solution to a black hole given the expression:

(dr/dtau)^2= Emu^2- Veff^2

As it is a square the sign in front of the root will depend on the turning points that I have manually found and labeled tp1 and tp2. However, even though I am changing the functions sign depending on its position it behaves relatively well until it hits these turning points.

Here is the code I have so far:
(P.S: I hope this is the correct formatting and way to present a question although i have been a reader for a few years this is actually my first post).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import ode



tp1 = 1.08329*10**11
tp2 = 4.13115*10**11


#arbitrary initial radius
r_start = 3e11
#constants:
M = 4*10**6*(1.9891*10**30) # SMBH mass in kg
G = 6.67408*10**(-11) # Gravitational constant in N kg^-2 m^2
c = 299792458


Emu2 = 0.88*10**17
Lmu = 10**19
def odes(tau,rs):
    
    Vef = (1-(((2*G*M)/c**2)/rs))*((c**2)+(Lmu/rs)**2)

    sign = (Emu2)-Vef
    signcount = 1
    if sign <= 0: 
        if rs <= tp1: 
            rs = tp1+5 
            Vef = (1-(((2*G*M)/c**2)/rs))*((c**2)+(Lmu/rs)**2)
            sign = (Emu2)-Vef
            drdTau = np.sqrt(Emu2 - Vef)
            signcount = 1
        if rs >= tp2:
            rs = tp2-5
            Vef = (1-(((2*G*M)/c**2)/rs))*((c**2)+(Lmu/rs)**2)
            sign = (Emu2)-Vef
            drdTau = (-1)*np.sqrt((Emu2) - Vef)
            signcount = 2
        return [drdTau]
    if sign > 0 :
        if signcount == 1: 
            Vef = (1-(((2*G*M)/c**2)/rs))*((c**2)+(Lmu/rs)**2)
            sign = (Emu2)-Vef
            drdTau = np.sqrt(Emu2 - Vef)
        if signcount == 2: 
            Vef = (1-(((2*G*M)/c**2)/rs))*((c**2)+(Lmu/rs)**2)
            sign = (Emu2)-Vef
            drdTau = (-1)*np.sqrt(Emu2 - Vef)
        return [drdTau]
            
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    
    r0 = [r_start]
    tspan = 5*3.154e7
    
    # timestep
    dtau = 1000
    
    # total number of steps
    n_steps = int(np.ceil(tspan/dtau))

    #Initialise arrays
    t = np.zeros((n_steps,1))
    rs = np.zeros((n_steps,1))
    ts = np.zeros((n_steps,1))
    step = 1


    r0 = [r_start]
    t0 = [0]
    t[0] = np.array(t0)
    rs[0] = np.array(r0)
# initiate solver
    solver = ode(odes)
    solver.set_integrator('DOP83')
    solver.set_initial_value(r0,0)
        
    #propagate orbit
    while solver.successful() and step<n_steps:
        solver.integrate(solver.t+dtau)
        ts[step] = solver.t
        rs[step] = solver.y
        step += 1

plt.plot(ts,rs,'s',color='#0066FF')
    

   
    # axes labels 
plt.xlabel('$x$') 
plt.ylabel('$y$')
plt.legend('pos')
    
    # check for and set axes limits
max_yval = np.amax(rs)
max_xval = np.amax(ts)
plt.xlim(0,max_xval)
plt.ylim(tp1 - 300000,max_yval)
    
plt.show()
print(rs)
```

Comment: Usually this is a bad idea, it would be far simpler to solve the second order equation that is the derivative of this one. One problem is that equations of the form `y'^2+V(y)=E` can stall at the turning points, switching to a constant segment is mathematically valid. /// Why do you define `Vef` multiple times with the same expression? Once should be enough.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have looked into this, but I think there are still sign dependancies based on the r turning points. I also dilike the treatment of Vef, I tried defining it up the top but it glitched the program so this was a quick fix until I can optimise it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by changing the function it is integrating once it reaches `tp1` and `tp2` I am hoping to add a root solver to automate the turning point solving but for now a rough tratment is what I have. I'll put up the code for anyone working on this area that has come across this issue once i have refined it, but essentially instead of modifying the function I added a second one called `odes2`with a negative sign and solved for that once the turning points were reached.

```
 solver = ode(odes)
 solver.set_integrator('lsoda')
 solver.set_initial_value(r0,0)
    
#propagate orbit
while solver.successful() and step<n_steps:
    solver.integrate(solver.t+dtau)
    ts[step] = solver.t
    rs[step] = solver.y
    if rs[step]>tp2:
        rs[step] = tp2 
        solver = ode(odes2)
        solver.set_initial_value(rs[step],ts[step])
    if rs[step]<tp1:
        rs[step] = tp1 
        solver = ode(odes)
        solver.set_initial_value(rs[step],ts[step])   
    step += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, but using the second order dynamic really avoids a lot of overhead

```
def Veff(rs): return (1-(((2*G*M)/c**2)/rs))*((c**2)+(Lmu/rs)**2)

def grad_Veff(rs):
    rp=rs*(1+1e-5)-1e-5; rm = rs*(1+1e-5)+1e-5
    return (Veff(rp)-Veff(rm))/(rp-rm);

def ode(t,y): return [y[1], -grad_Veff(y[0])]

t = np.arange(0, tspan, dtau)

vstart = (Emu2 - Veff(rstart))**0.5

res = solve_ivp(ode, (0,tspan), [rstart, vstart], t_eval=t, atol=1e2, rtol=1e-8)
```

This should integrate through the turning points, to find the turning points search for sign changes or roots in the second component. One could also define an event for this so that the solver automatically registers the turning points.